# Powershell Process watchdog

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell

I'd like to know if there is way to create some kind of watchdog using power shell, that monitors specific processes and if they hang the watchdog should try to restart them and send and email if it can't.

I'd also like to know if it's possible that this script can be run as a service.

I'm using Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

You can get list of not responding processes using:

```
Get-Process | ? Responding -EQ $false
```

But I don't know if this is reliable solution. Process may not respond for many reasons and later get back to normal by itself.